# Error when trying to use Open Tok React Native library, otk_anvil.cpp:467

Tags: react-native, opentok

I'm trying to use the Open Tok React Native library, https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react-native/, but I keep getting an error:

```
[ERROR] otk_anvil.cpp:467 - otk_anvil_on_session_info failed. nCode=1
[ERROR] rumor_client_v1.c:312 - otk_rumor_v1_client_send (pClient == NULL) rumor client is not initialized and cannot send message
```

Can't figure it out what is causing it.

I tried to test their sample but I'm getting the same error. Even a clean/new project is resulting in the same.

Current setup:

```
➜  BasicVideoChat git:(master) ✗ react-native -v
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.59.5
```

Xcode: 10.3 on macOS Mojave (10.14.6)

```
<OTSession
              apiKey={this.apiKey}
              sessionId={this.sessionId}
              token={this.token}>
              <OTPublisher style={{width: 100, height: 100}} />
              <OTSubscriber style={{width: 100, height: 100}} />
            </OTSession>
```

It should render the user and subscribers videos, but I'm only getting a blank/white screen with those logs on console.

Comment: Do you have the correct key values?

Comment: Yes I do, I could run it with their OpenTokJS library on a browser, I'm using the same keys on react native.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed that error was caused by an expired token. Even when I was able to use it via browser it was expiring before I test it on the device.